# Recursive .reduce() to output an array of parents

Tags: javascript, recursion, reduce

I have an flat array of Folders like this one :

```
const foldersArray = [{id: "1", parentId: null, name: "folder1"}, {id: "2", parentId: null, name: "folder2"}, {id: "1.1", parentId: 1, name: "folder1.1"}, {id: "1.1.1", parentId: "1.1", name: "folder1.1.1"},{id: "2.1", parentId: 2, name: "folder2.1"}]
```

I want to output an array of all parents of a given folder to generate a Breadcrumb-like component of Folder path.

I have presently a code that does what I need but I'd like to write it better in a more "functional" way, using reduce recursively.

If I do :

```
    getFolderParents(folder){ 
      return this.foldersArray.reduce((all, item) => { 
        if (item.id === folder.parentId) { 
            all.push (item.name) 
            this.getFolderParents(item)
         }
         return all
       }, [])
     }
```

and I log the output, I can see it successfully finds the first Parent, then reexecute the code, and outputs the parent's parent... as my initial array is logically reset to [] at each step... Can't find a way around though...

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about it in a backwards way. You have a single `folder` as input and you wish to *expand* it to a breadcrumb list of *many* folders. This is actually the opposite of `reduce` which takes as input many values, and returns a single value.

Reduce is also known as *fold*, and the reverse of a fold is *unfold*. `unfold` accepts a looping function `f` and an `init` state. Our function is given loop controllers `next` which add value to the output and specifies the next state, and `done` which signals the end of the loop.

```js
const unfold = (f, init) =>
  f ( (value, nextState) => [ value, ...unfold (f, nextState) ]
    , () => []
    , init
    )

const range = (m, n) =>
  unfold
    ( (next, done, state) =>
        state > n
          ? done ()
          : next ( state        // value to add to output
                 , state + 1    // next state
                 )
    , m // initial state
    )

console.log (range (3, 10))
// [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

Above, we start with an initial state of a number, `m` in this case. Just like the accumulator variable in reduce, you can specify any initial state to `unfold`. Below, we express your program using `unfold`. We add `parent` to make it easy to select a folder's parent

```
const parent = ({ parentId }) =>
  data .find (f => f.id === String (parentId))

const breadcrumb = folder =>
  unfold
    ( (next, done, f) =>
        f == null
          ? done ()
          : next ( f          // add folder to output
                 , parent (f) // loop with parent folder
                 )
    , folder // init state
    )

breadcrumb (data[3])
// [ { id: '1.1.1', parentId: '1.1', name: 'folder1.1.1' }
// , { id: '1.1', parentId: 1, name: 'folder1.1' }
// , { id: '1', parentId: null, name: 'folder1' } ]

breadcrumb (data[4])
// [ { id: '2.1', parentId: 2, name: 'folder2.1' }
// , { id: '2', parentId: null, name: 'folder2' } ]

breadcrumb (data[0])
//  [ { id: '1', parentId: null, name: 'folder1' } ]
```

You can verify the results of the program below

```js
const data =
  [ {id: "1", parentId: null, name: "folder1"}
  , {id: "2", parentId: null, name: "folder2"}
  , {id: "1.1", parentId: 1, name: "folder1.1"}
  , {id: "1.1.1", parentId: "1.1", name: "folder1.1.1"}
  , {id: "2.1", parentId: 2, name: "folder2.1"}
  ]
  
const unfold = (f, init) =>
  f ( (value, state) => [ value, ...unfold (f, state) ]
    , () => []
    , init
    )

const parent = ({ parentId }) =>
  data .find (f => f.id === String (parentId))

const breadcrumb = folder =>
  unfold
    ( (next, done, f) =>
        f == null
          ? done ()
          : next ( f          // add folder to output
                 , parent (f) // loop with parent folder
                 )
    , folder // init state
    )

console.log (breadcrumb (data[3]))
// [ { id: '1.1.1', parentId: '1.1', name: 'folder1.1.1' }
// , { id: '1.1', parentId: 1, name: 'folder1.1' }
// , { id: '1', parentId: null, name: 'folder1' } ]
   
console.log (breadcrumb (data[4]))
// [ { id: '2.1', parentId: 2, name: 'folder2.1' }
// , { id: '2', parentId: null, name: 'folder2' } ]

console.log (breadcrumb (data[0]))
//  [ { id: '1', parentId: null, name: 'folder1' } ]
```

If you trace the computation above, you see that `find` is called once per folder `f` added to the outupt in the unfolding process. This is an expensive operation, and if your `data` set is significantly large, could be a problem for you.

A better solution would be to create an additional representation of your data that has a structure better suited for this type of query. If all you do is create a `Map` of `f.id -> f`, you can decrease lookup time from linear to logarithmic.

`unfold` is really powerful and suited for a wide variety of problems. I have [many other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A633183+unfold) relying on it in various ways. There's even some dealing with asynchrony in there, too.

If you get stuck, don't hesitate to ask follow-up questions :D

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a `Map` so you avoid iterating over the array each time you need to retrieve the next parent. This way you get an *O(n)* instead of an *O(n²)* time complexity:

```js
const foldersArray = [{id: "1", parentId: null, name: "folder1"}, {id: "2", parentId: null, name: "folder2"}, {id: "1.1", parentId: "1", name: "folder1.1"}, {id: "1.1.1", parentId: "1.1", name: "folder1.1.1"},{id: "2.1", parentId: "2", name: "folder2.1"}];
const folderMap = new Map(foldersArray.map( o => [o.id, o] ));
const getFolderParents = folder => 
    (folder.parentId ? getFolderParents(folderMap.get(folder.parentId)) : [])
    .concat(folder.name);

// Example call:
console.log(getFolderParents(foldersArray[4]));
```

Just a minor remark: your `parentId` data type is not consistent: it better be always a string, just like the data type of the `id` property. If not, you need to cast it in your code, but it is really better to have the data type right from the start. You'll notice that I have defined `parentId` as a string consistently: this is needed for the above code to work. Alternatively, cast it to string in the code with `String(folder.parentId)`.

Secondly, the above code will *pre*-pend the parent folder name (like is done in file folder notations). If you need to append the parent name *after* the child, then swap the `concat` subject and argument:

```
[folder.name].concat(folder.parentId ? getFolderParents(folderMap.get(folder.parentId)) : []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you're looking for with a rather ugly looking while loop. Gets the job done though. Each loop iteration filters, looking for an instance of a parent. If that doesn't exist, it stops and exits. If it does exist, it pushes that parent into the `tree` array, sets `folder` to its parent to move up a level, then moves on to the next iteration.

```js
const foldersArray = [{
  id: "1",
  parentId: null,
  name: "folder1"
}, {
  id: "2",
  parentId: null,
  name: "folder2"
}, {
  id: "1.1",
  parentId: 1,
  name: "folder1.1"
}, {
  id: "1.1.1",
  parentId: "1.1",
  name: "folder1.1.1"
}, {
  id: "2.1",
  parentId: 2,
  name: "folder2.1"
}]

function getParents(folder){
 const tree = [], storeFolder = folder
  let parentFolder
  while((parentFolder = foldersArray.filter(t => t.id == folder.parentId)[0]) !== undefined){
    tree.push(parentFolder)
    folder = parentFolder
  }
  
  console.log({ originalFolder: storeFolder, parentTree: tree})
}

getParents(foldersArray[3])
```